# Migradoc - How do I align a Shapes.Image object?

Tags: image, alignment, migradoc

```
Dim _image as Shapes.Image = section.Header.Primary.AddImage(filepath)
```

Using the example above, I want to align the image to the left, center, or right.
I'm placing this under the headers.

Is it also possible to have two logos under headers to be aligned to the right and left.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to create a table with those images and then place it all in the Header.